# Merge prefix and suffix from 2 files

Tags: string, awk, merge

I would like to merge 2 files:

```
> cat file1.txt
string1:suffix1
string2:suffix2

> cat file2.txt
prefix1:string1
prefix2:string2
```

in:

```
> cat result.txt
prefix1:string1:suffix1
prefix2:string2:suffix2
```

How is it possible to use awk (?) to do that?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F: 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} 
                   {print $0 FS a[$2]}' file1 file2

prefix1:string1:suffix1
prefix2:string2:suffix2
```

or if the files are already aligned

```
$ paste -d: file2 <(cut -d: -f2 file1)

prefix1:string1:suffix1
prefix2:string2:suffix2
```

Comment: Thanks! Prefered answer for using 'paste' command I did not know before.

Answer (score 1):

awk 'BEGIN {OFS=":"}{ getline line < "file1.txt" ;split(line, a, ":");print $1,a[2];} ' file2.txt

where,
This [ {OFS=":"} ] is to set the character to use to append 2 lines from 2 files, if you use space you will get an output like below:
prefix1:string1 suffix1
prefix2:string2 suffix2

This [ getline line < "file1.txt" ] is to get lines from first file.
This [ split(line, a, ":") ] is to split the line based on colon and create an array a.
This [ print $1 ] is to print entire line of file2.txt file
This [ a[2] ] is to print the 2nd element of the array a from first file

Comment: Works well, Thank you!